# HTML tags in translation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, gettext

I'm trying to translate a string that contains HTML tags, but Laravel blade returns me in plain text.

```
{{ _i('The <b>%s</b> referral program is a great way to spread the word of this great service and to earn even more money with your short links! Refer friends and receive %s of their earnings for life!', 'gano.com', '20%') }}
```

result:

```
The <b>gano.com</b> referral program is a great way to spread the word of this great service and to earn even more money with your short links! Refer friends and receive 20% of their earnings for life!
```

I'm using the following Laravel package.

https://github.com/Belphemur/laravel-gettext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below two options for this:

```
{!! _i('The <b>%s</b> referral program is a great way to spread the word of this great service and to earn even more money with your short links! Refer friends and receive %s of their earnings for life!', 'gano.com', '20%') !!}

{!!html_entity_decode(_i('The <b>%s</b> referral program is a great way to spread the word of this great service and to earn even more money with your short links! Refer friends and receive %s of their earnings for life!', 'gano.com', '20%'))!!}
```

Both should work fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

you can render the html tags like so:

`{!! 'this text will be <b>bold</b>.' !!}`

Output: this text will be **bold**.

Laravel uses `{{ }}` to escape tags in order to prevent XSS attacks.

But in any case you need to render the html tags inside the variable, you can use `{!! !!}`